# addEventListener to iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouse

I'm tryin to add event listener to mouseup inside iframe object:

```
$("#myIFrame").contents().find("body").bind("mouseup", function() {
    //e.preventDefault(); //doesn't make difference
    alert('inside');
});
```

This doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Binding to events in iFrames can be problematic because doing so sometimes captures events that are intended for the content hosted by the IFRAME itself; how this gets handled varies among browsers.

Comment: What this gives to you? --> `alert($("#myIFrame").contents().find("body").length)`

Comment: And the iFrame is of course showing a page from the same domain, with the same port and protocol ?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I get 1

Comment: @adeneo yes, same domain/port/protocol

Comment: @DarkoMartic Then it should work!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak well, it doesn't :) 
I don't get alert('inside');

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work:

```
 $('#myIFrame').load(function(){
     //then set up some access points
     var contents = $(this).contents(); // contents of the iframe
     $(contents).find("body").on('mouseup', function(event) { 
         alert('test'); 
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 22):

If you just want a plain vanilla Javascript way, you can use the following:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
iframe.contentDocument.body.addEventListener('mouseup', Handler);

function Handler() {
    alert('works');
}
```

Comment: Sometimes `contentDocument` does not exist, so try `contentWindow` in stead of it. Example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument

Comment: Yes, in Chrome 79, this code worked for me only when changing it to `iframe.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('mouseup', Handler);`

Comment: Hey Vince, nice profile pic.

Comment: for me contentDocument / contenWindow did not work, but this did:`var iframe_1 = document.getElementById('1_html');
iframe_1.onload = Handler_1;
function Handler_1() {
   alert('works 1');  
}`

Answer (score 3):

Try this working on chrome, just tested

As per my knowledge, Iframe must be from same domain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(window).load(function () {            
            var $frame = $("#myIFrame");
            $frame.contents().bind("mouseup", function (e) {
                alert('inside');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="myIFrame" src="/WebForm4.aspx" style="position:absolute; width:500px; height:500px;left:0px; top:50px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it wont work on jsfiddle, because it mark that script as CDATA. Try this on your local machine.

Answer (score 3):

## iframe.contentWindow

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
iframe.contentWindow.body.addEventListener('click',() => console.log('click'));
```

### Mind the cross-origin policy

Event bubbling will be allowed only if frames have the same origin.
Unless you will get next error (Chrome):

`Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame`

Comment: Thanks  Your approach works perfectly, but I add to use 'contentDocument' instead of 'contentWindow'. iframe.contentDocument.body.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click'));

Comment: Then how we can approach for cross domain origin.

Answer (score 1):

```
$($("#iframeid").contents()[0], window).find('body').bind("mouseup", function(e) {
    alert("works");
});
```

Try  this. Works in jsfiddle. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

To give trigger event to your iframe there is an alternate way:
Wrap ifrmae inside a div and give onClick event to the div. So that onClick of div you can give trigger event on click of iframe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).