# Prevent content copying from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to prevent copying content loaded in iframe. I am using the following code [[per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30398393)], and it works fine.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(window).load(function () {            
            var $frame = $("#tif");
            $frame.contents().bind("copy", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="whatever.com" height="768" width="1366" id="tif"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

But when a pdf file is given as the source, the above code fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: You think you've prevented content copying? Good luck with that

Comment: Yeah, if the loaded content origins from same domain

Comment: @NeeradVaidya Anyone who wants to copy is going to disable JavaScript, or use the developer tools, or any of a number of other approaches. Trying to stop people from copying text is pointless and simply not possible.

Comment: the only way to prevent someone from copying content is to not send it (I think that's a Zen quote)

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah I know and I understand, but this is weird ask from my client. I tried to make them understand but it did not worked out. So I had no other option to ask you folks.

Comment: @JaromandaX nice quote...